# Why the basic example of service in ROS2 doesnt use rosidl?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the migrating article from ROS to ROS2, it says that for messages and services we have to add on CMakeLists.txt and on package.xml some rosidl lines. So why on "Writing a simple service and client (C++)" it doesnt use it and in which cases we should use it?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399548/why-the-basic-example-of-service-in-ros2-doesnt-use-rosidl?/) by [Peanpepu](https://answers.ros.org/users/102601/peanpepu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2022-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-25**:
Can you link us these articles? Especially the first one about migrating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure if this is it, but in the ROS2 tutorials the package `example_interfaces` is used - [there in `CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) you have these lines:

```
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "action/Fibonacci.action"
  ...
  "srv/Trigger.srv"
)
install(FILES mapping_rules.yaml DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
ament_package()
```

and [in `package.xml`](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces/blob/master/package.xml):

```
<package format="3">
  <name>example_interfaces</name>
  <version>0.9.3</version>
  <description>Contains message and service definitions used by the examples.</description>
  <maintainer email="mabel@openrobotics.org">Mabel Zhang</maintainer>
  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>
  <author email="dthomas@openrobotics.org">Dirk Thomas</author>
  <author email="jacob@openrobotics.org">Jacob Perron</author>
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
  <depend>action_msgs</depend>
  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
```

A note about `package_name_interfaces` from https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Single-Package-Define-And-Use-Interface.html :

> While best practice is to declare
> interfaces in dedicated interface
> packages, sometimes it can be
> convenient to declare, create and use
> an interface all in one package.

The dependencies in the basic service examples are fulfilled with `ament_target_dependencies(service_main rclcpp example_interfaces)` in their `CMakeLists.txt` (e.g. https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclcpp/services/minimal_service/CMakeLists.txt).

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peanpepu](https://answers.ros.org/users/102601/peanpepu/) on 2022-04-25**:
Ok thank you. However, if i want to use a srv from my own folder i have to include all these rosidl stuff, isnt it?
The migrating article is this one: "https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Contributing/Migration-Guide.html"
And the service basic example is the one you have seen: "https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Service-And-Client.html"

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-25**:
Overall, yes - you can use ament macro `ament_target_dependencies` in your package too (https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html#adding-dependencies)

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-04-25**:
If this is the correct answer, please upvote and accept it so others can see that it has been answered